# MediaStore External Content URI is fetching data from SDCARD

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, mediastore

I am using MediaStore and Cursor to fetch audio files from a specified folder. What I want is that, it should fetch the list of songs from the phone's internal storage but it is fetching from SDCARD. Although I have tried using INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI but it is not getting anything at all. Kindly have a look, what's wrong in it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    String AudioFilePath = "%" +"/nexcox/voicerecorder/audio/" +"%";

    Uri uri= MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection= MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA +" LIKE ? ";
    Cursor cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(uri,null,selection,
            new String[]{AudioFilePath},
            null);


    if (cursor!=null){
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String duration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));
                String sourceLocation = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

                AudioInfo audioInfo=new AudioInfo(name,duration,sourceLocation);
                audioInfos.add(audioInfo);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        audioAdapter=new AudioAdapter(context,audioInfos);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(audioAdapter);
}
```

Comment: You will get data from the Media database which holds all media details, both from internal and external storage. You can test the _DATA column which holds the full path for each entry.

Comment: Can you be more specific. If you could tell me, what I need to change in the above code to fix the issue. That will be very kind of you.

Answer (score 1):

for example

```
     String fullpath = trackcursor.getString(trackcursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA))

if(fullpath.contains(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(){
// you have the internal sdcard
}
```

In your code:

```
        if (cursor!=null){
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String duration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));
                String sourceLocation = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

                    if(sourceLocation.contains(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(){
    // you have the internal sdcard
     AudioInfo audioInfo=new AudioInfo(name,duration,sourceLocation);
                audioInfos.add(audioInfo);
    } 

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        audioAdapter=new AudioAdapter(context,audioInfos);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(audioAdapter);
}
```

Comment: The database holds the full path and that is what we are testing for. Granted your code should work but if it doesnt, try selecting without the LIKE ? etc

Comment: I have figured out the issue, it is the cursor which is not refreshing. it gives the old values, no matter how many files have been added. it never says, a new entry has added.
Do you know, how can I refresh this cursor ? I am using adapter that is already extending recyclerView.

Comment: have a look at notifyDatasetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

I use the same approach as your example. Works fine.

```
     public Cursor getMediastoreTrackDetails(Context context, String trackName) {
    if(context!=null) {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        final String _id = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
        final String path = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
        final String album = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM;
        final String album_id = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID;
        final String[] columns = {_id, path,album, album_id};
        final String[] trackname = {"%" + trackName + "%"};
        String where = path + " LIKE ?";
        return  cr.query(uri, columns, where, trackname, null);
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```